# Same notes above each other

Tags: sheet-music

Ii was looking to some, for me, more advanced sheet music and I found that there are 3 note lines. The problem, which got me confused, were the same notes above each other. (see picture).

[image]
[image]

How is this supposed to be played? Thnak you for help

Comment: Did you mean to post the same bit of music twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piano player only plays the lower two lines - the top line is what the singer sings.

Comment: And, just to call it out: In the circled bit (and probably the rest of the arrangement?) the piano "doubles" the singer's notes. If you're playing for your own enjoyment, without a singer, this helps provide the part that everyone thinks of as "the song." If you're playing along with a singer, you could play those notes to help support them, or sometimes leave them out if they're too much (https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/116669/impossible-piano-fingering-in-sondheim).