# Is it possible to play this B-flat, F, D chord?

Tags: piano, chords

[image: the chord]

Source: bar 38 in https://musescore.com/user/22588026/scores/4596391

My hand can span a bit over one octave but this chord is well out of reach. Is it even physically possible to play it as written?

Assuming not, what is a good way to deal with it? I reviewed the answers in [What is the best way to play a chord larger than your hand?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110111/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-a-chord-larger-than-your-hand). I don't think an arpeggio makes sense here since this part of the song is supposed to sound delicate rather than extravagant. The D is repeated in the right hand, so I think it makes sense to skip the D in the left hand.

Comment: I hear you loud and clear about the problem. It is physically possible for some people (I can do it), but in this case, try item #5 in the post you mentioned — I've fleshed it out to make more clear how to apply it. However, leaving out the D (item #7) is also a good solution. That would double simplify things, because you would omit the following E as well.

Comment: @Aaron thanks. Just to clarify, are you suggesting to play the Bb as a grace note into F-D? I can try that. I also use the sustain pedal here, so I wouldn't necessarily need to omit the E after skipping D.

Comment: I would try both playing the Bb as a grace note and Bb-F as a "grace chord", to see which you like better. My inclination would be to try Bb-F first. If you do omit the D, the E won't make as much sense, since it's part of a melodic progression.

Comment: I found a recording of the composer himself playing the piece, and he is indeed using a grace note/arpeggio technique to play these chords. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQ-tyfJt0tc