# How do you play this chord? It's too far apart to play with one hand. (piano)

Tags: piano, chords

[image]

My left hand is too far down to help, so I can't use it. How would I play it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to play a chord larger than your hand?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110111/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-a-chord-larger-than-your-hand)

Comment: @PiedPiper Hm—the proposed duplicate assumes that the "impossibility" is caused by notes that all start simultaneously. It never mentions what I would assume is the easiest answer here, "who says your left hand has to stay down there; just use the pedal for a second."

Comment: @AndyBonner That's a great point. I'll add that to the proposed duplicate later today, so everything is in one place.

Comment: I'm going to add a solution to the post proposed as a duplicate. Could you add the title and composer of this piece so that I can include that in the post?

Comment: @AndyBonner or play the C an octave higher, or [who says you have to use only your hands?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/131042/2257)

Comment: The dot is telling you to start on middle C and then jump to the other notes as quickly as possible.

Comment: @user207421 that's not what the dot usually means -- it usually applies to the whole chord to which it is applied -- and it it not the usual way of showing that, which would be to write the middle C as a grace note.

Answer (score 1):

I would play the C an octave higher.  Yes, you can use the pedal or even just play the low D staccato to free your left hand to help, but it's still a big and awkward leap.
At a fast tempo it will be very difficult to execute correctly.

Raising the C by an octave is no crime in music of this style.  On top of this, the composer or arranger should have made some provision for players who can't span a tenth, and the fact that there is no such provision means that most players will have to make some compromise or other.  The most natural such compromise is to revoice the chord in the right hand.

If you find the change in the chord's sonority to be excessive then your only other options are to release the bass D (with or without the pedal) or to use your nose.

Answer (score 1):

Some pianists could stretch this.  If you can't, cheat.   Either leave out the C or include it in the chord an octave higher.